# I can't boot Sony Xperia C into fastboot mode

Tags: android, sony, sony-xperia, fastboot

I am unable to boot my Xperia C into fastboot mode. I got unlock bootloader key from Sony site & wanted to flash it to unlock bootloader. I used the Volume up button as stated in the Sony site to boot into fastboot mode but the device doesn't boot into fastboot mode and goes into charging mode ! Now how do i do it ?

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem than you with my Xperia S.

I assuming you have followed this process:
http://developer.sonymobile.com/unlockbootloader/

The problem is that Windows can't find the proper driver for the fastboot connection by itself. So that, open the Device Manager and just when the phone is connected (turns light on in blue, in my case) it will appear under tab Unknow Devices with the name "S1boot..." or something similar. Right-click on it (be fast my friend!!) and select "update driver". Now you should be able to point to the google usb_driver folder, where it is the android_winusb.inf file you have replaced it in a previous step...You should get a "Device Succesfully Installed" Windows message.

Next time you reboot your device in bootloader mode you'll stay on it (hopefully).

Regards!

Comment: worked for me. the only thing i have to add is that if the driver is "faulty" you will need to reboot the system using a guide like in "Disabling Driver Signature on Windows 8" to do this. 
I was doing this for a xperia so don't forget to add the 6 lines into the inf file under android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf the lines needed are found under the file found in http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/fastboot-driver/

Answer (score 1):

Try using another USB cable or maybe hold the the volume up button longer even after the red light appears and wait for the BLUE light